# Magento 2.0.2 right to left

Tags: right-to-left, magento2

I would like to translate Magento 2.0 to a right-to-left language (Hebrew, Arabic or Parsian).

Do I need to create a new theme for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to create a new theme for RTL

For creation of a new theme you can take help from the magento 1.x theme

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rtl-default-theme.html